# Necessity of COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE when saving data via SQLite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

In the basic Android tutorials that Google provides, the section on [putting information into a database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#WriteDbRow) using the `insert()` function involves using a column called `COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE` which had not been listed before in describing the [schema](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DefineContract) or database itself via `SQLiteOpenDbHelper`, so I had assumed that it was generated automatically by implementation of `BaseColumns`, similary to the `_ID` column.

However, according to Eclipse this is not the case. As such, does this mean in my initial schema/contract I have to create a column (and this is not generated automatically by implementation of `BaseColumns`)?

Furthermore, what is the use of this column? Will it just contain the `String "null"` if there is no `ContentValues` and will it remain blank and unused if `ContentValues` is not null?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but the FeedEntry class is just an example of a type of objects that are to be stored in the DB. So also the COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE constant is related to this class so I guess you cannot use it without implementing it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. In that case how can the framework insert NULL should ContentValues be empty, as it says it states at the bottom of [this section](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#WriteDbRow)? As in, would I have to use some extra method or will it be automatic via the `db.insert()` method?

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation says, nullColumnHack is

> optional; may be null. SQL doesn't allow inserting a completely empty row without naming at least one column name. If your provided values is empty, no column names are known and an empty row can't be inserted. If not set to null, the nullColumnHack parameter provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly insert a NULL into in the case where your values is empty.

So the nullColumnHack will be a name of one of the columns in your database that can contain a null value.

If you are sure the contentValues you insert into the DB will never be null or will never contain only null values, you can leave the nullColumnHack without a name, and thus, null.

If you tried to insert null ContentValues, it would probably throw an error.

Comment: A `ContentValues` object containing null values is fine; the hack is only for an empty `ContentValues`.